# Table in Word doc, ConvertToText VB NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

Been searching for an answer to this but everybody seems to want to do the opposite!

Using VB.NET code I want to convert all the tables in an open word doc to text but when I run the following code, I get the error

> "'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020951-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

Have I got the code wrong or is this not possible? I'm guessing I've got it wrong!

```
Dim objTable As Table = objDoc.Tables

If objTable.Rows.Count = 1 Or objTable.Columns.Count = 1 Then
    objTable.ConvertToText(Separator:=vbCr)
End If
```

Comment: You are setting `objTable` equal to the document's table collection not a specific table. i.e. `objDoc.Tables.Item(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in a comment, the `Tables` collection doesn't have the method to convert tables to text, only the `Table` object (singular) has it. This means it's necessary to iterate (loop) the items in the collection. For example:

```
Dim objTables as Tables = objDoc.Tables
Dim objTable As Table
For each objTable in objTables
    If objTable.Rows.Count = 1 Or objTable.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        objTable.ConvertToText(Separator:=vbCr)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks so much for this. problem well and truly solved